# Captcha script generates a failure response

Tags: php, forms, validation, captcha

I just started learning php, tried to use it to create a validation script for a contact form but it always returns an error even if the user inputs a correct number:

```
 <?php
    session_start ();
    $_SESSION['safe']=rand(1000,9999);
    if(isset($_POST['nazwa']) && isset ($_POST['dane'])  &&isset($_POST['message'])) 
    {
        $name = $_POST['nazwa'];
        $email = $_POST['dane'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($message)) {

        if(strlen ($name)>50||strlen($email)>50||strlen($message)>1000) {echo 'Character limit exceeded ';  } else 
            {
                $from = 'z formularza nazwastrony';
                $to = 'roman.pliszka@yahoo.com';
                $subject = 'wiadomosc ze strony';
                $body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

                if (!isset($_POST['check'])) {
                $_SESSION['safe']=rand(1000,9999);
                } else {
                    if ($_SESSION['safe'] == $_POST['check']) {
                        if ($_POST['submit']) 
                        { 
                        if (@mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) 
                    {
                        echo '<p>Message sent</p>';
                    } else 
                    {
                        echo '<p>An error occurred</p>';
                    } 
                }
    }else {
        echo 'Incorrect number';
        $_SESSION['safe']=rand(1000,9999);
    }
    }
    }
        } else {
            echo 'Please fill all of the fields';
        }
    } 
    ?>
```

the script uses generate.php for generating an image:

```
<?php
session_start();
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$text = $_SESSION['safe'];
$font_size = 30;

$image_width = 100;
$image_height = 40;

$image = imagecreate ($image_width, $image_height);
imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

for ($x=1; $x<50; $x++) {
    $x1 = rand(1, 100);
    $y1 = rand(1, 100);
    $x2 = rand(1, 100);
    $y2 = rand(1, 100);

    imageline($image, $x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $text_color);
}

imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, 15, 30, $text_color, 'font.ttf', $text);
imagejpeg($image);
?>
```

Basiclly, in all cases I get "Incorrect number". My guess is that the php session changes generating another random number but I wasn't able to write this code correctly. All the names in the script and html form are the same. I would be gratefull for any help.

edit: this is a fragment of a form with user input:

```
        <image src="generate.php" />
        <input type="text" name="check">
```

Comment: i dont see you making a real check for any capcha text, you just check if name/email/message fields of POST are present

Comment: if ($_SESSION['safe'] == $_POST['check']) - this is the condition for checking if 'check' (user input) equals 'safe' which is generated by a script. At least that what i had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problem is the order of your statements. You should process the POST data BEFORE you generate a new random code in the session. Otherwise, you always create a new code than the one sent by the user. I would change things a bit:

```
<?php
session_start();
// PROCESS POST DATA - RETURN CORRESPONDING MESSAGE
function processPostData() {
    $code="";
    // CHECK IF POST DATA WAS SENT
    if (isset($_POST["check"])) {
        $code=$_POST["check"];
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    // CHECK CODE
    if ($code != $_SESSION["safe"]) {
        return "<p>Incorrect number</p>";
    }
    // CHECK NON-EMPTY
    if (empty($_POST['nazwa']) || empty($_POST['dane']) || empty($_POST['message'])) {
        return "<p>Please fill all of the fields</p>";
    } else{
        // GET POST DATA
        $name = $_POST['nazwa'];
        $email = $_POST['dane'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
    }   
    // CHECK MAX LENGTH
    if(strlen ($name)>50||strlen($email)>50||strlen($message)>1000) {
        return "<p>Character limit exceeded</p>";
    }
    /* VALIDATE DATA HERE: email (look for good validation scripts) */

    // SEND EMAIL
    if (@mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
        return "<p>Message sent</p>";
    } else {
        return "<p>An error occurred</p>";
    }
}

// PROCESS POST DATA - IF SET
echo processPostData();

// GENERATE NEW CODE EVERY TIME -! AFTER PROCESSING POST DATA
$_SESSION["safe"]=rand(1000,9999);

?>
```

PS. the problem was on line 3 of your code - move that at the end and it should work. Still, I think it would be safer to use a proper API. I use: [Google's reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html)

Comment: Thank you very much dear sir! :D You've solved my problem. I'll probably end up using an Api (as you suggested) but for now I want to learn as much as I can by doing things "by hand".

Comment: Cheers! I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see code of the form, but it seems, that you are using wrong variable to generate text on captcha. Try replacing

```
$text = $_SESSION['bezpieczny'];
```

with

```
$text = $_SESSION['safe'];
```

Comment: Thanks for youre quick response. I was translating my variables to english before posting the code here and forgot to change the one from generat.php. In files though the names match.